# How can I let people send me money via PayPal without them seeing my PayPal account info?

Tags: paypal, donation

Two things to start of with: one, I don't know if this is the right StackExchange website for this, and second of all, my title doesn't make much sense, so her is the concept of the question:

I would like to receive donations over PayPal, but I don't want people to see my PayPal email, full name, address, etc. Basically, they pay money to the website, who then pay it to me (probably with taxes knowing companies that handle money). I have heard Patreon has such a thing, but I haven't checked to get it confirmed.

So here is my question: is there any (non sketchy) website that allows me to be anonymous when receiving money?

Comment: The thing is that trying to receive money totally anonymously is inherently sketchy.  How would anyone know that they're not just being scammed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The thing to look at is PayPal's "PayPal.me" service, which is a pretty neat little item.  When you sign up for a PayPal.me account (totally free), you create a unique username.  So for example, my PayPal.me account name is DanCAnderson.  I can give someone the following web link to send me $500:

http://paypal.me/DanCAnderson/500

If you click the link above, you'll see what the user sees (my company name is Salt River Networks, Inc.).  I gave a live link so you can see the working example of it (*no need for anyone to send money!* chuckle).

I can change the amount by simply changing the value at the end of the URL.

When they go to that link, they see a landing page with your name on it and the amount to send to you, then they go through the normal process of paying via PayPal.

It's a pretty neat service, and I've used to it bill a few clients for work I've done by emailing that link to them rather than going through the whole PayPal procedure.

Comment: Wouldn't that show a person''s name in the payment history or  whatever you call it though? Also, I don't have a business account, so would my PayPal account name be displayed instead?

Comment: If you don't have a business account then yes, your name would appear on the PayPal.me page.  You can't get around your name coming up in the PayPal transaction history, because people have to be able to know who they're paying and to dispute unauthorized transactions.  You aren't going to find a totally anonymous payment method in the mainstream.  This is as close as I can think you'll be able to get.

Comment: "...no need for anyone to send money! chuckle..." Oops I just sent $500. Can you do an electronic transfer to my account as refund :)

Comment: How can this help with privacy if when I try to create paypal.me it forces to accept this? 
"I agree that my name, photo, username, email, and mobile can be shown to others to make it easier to find me on PayPal and to transact with me, and I agree to the Terms & Conditions and Privacy Policy."

Answer (score 0):

What you are thinking about is bitcoin probably where people are and can be anonymous. I would suggest you to look that up.